# How proper define ParameterOverride for abstract type in constructor for IUnityContainer

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have some classes:

```
public class Inspector
{
        private readonly BaseType someType;

        public Inspector(BaseType someType)
        {
            this.someType= someType;
        }
}

public abstract class BaseType {}

public class TypeA : BaseType {}

public class TypeB : BaseType {}
```

and IoC container setup for them:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<Inspector>();
```

then during runtime I have call to something like this:

```
var typeA = new TypeA(); //It could be also TypeB
var inspector = container.Resolve<Inspector>(new ParameterOverride(typeA.GetType(), typeA));
```

but this `Resolve<Inspector>()` gives me an exception:
*The current type, BaseType, is an abstract class and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?*
It looks like parameter override is ignored and container tries find BaseType registration in it. Of course registration of TypeA and TypeB doesn't solve the problem. Anyway I don't want register all subtypes of BaseType in the container because there is a lot of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnityContainer` tries to resolve `BaseType`, not a type inhertied from `BaseType`.

So you need to create the override for `BaseType`:

```
var inspector = container.Resolve<Inspector>(new ParameterOverride(typeof(BaseType), typeA));
```